# VLC not showing subtitles (Ubuntu 16.04 gnome)

Tags: 16.04, vlc, ubuntu-gnome, subtitle

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop and I am trying to play .mkv file with .srt.

Vlc loads the .srt and displays it in sub track list but it doesn't display anything on video. Video and audio works fine. I tried different fonts and edited .srt so it has only few english letters in it to diplay for some time but still nothing.

There are no errors or any messages in VLC>tools>messages.

I'm trying to fix it last two hours but nothing works. removing config file, purging all vlc packages and reinstalling. nothing.

EDIT:

I just realized there is no text displaying over video at all. Not even the "Subtitle loaded". I booted VirtualBox with ubuntu 16.04 and works just fine. I am not sure if this is problem with gnome.

EDIT2:

Switching back to ubuntu from login screen did not fix the problem.

EDIT3:

I installed gnome and tweak tools on VM as well and tried and it still works. WTF is up with mine then?!

Comment: Good to see the issue is resolved :). Probably the question needs to be closed as it is unlikely to be reproduced by other users....

Comment: I can't accept my answer as the solution until 48h pass. And I will get my account suspended for deleting the question. not sure if I can close it any other way.

Comment: Don't worry the process is underway....

Answer (score 0):

After whole night of research and trying different things ... reinstalled ubuntu.